# Combine two SELECT statements to create output in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

*So I'm trying to combine the output of these two statements:*

```
SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE MILES BETWEEN 3 AND 5;
```

*This total gives me 8*

```
SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER;
```

*This total gives me 20 (total number of rows in my database)

This gives me an answer of who from my database lives within 3 and 5 miles, where miles is its own column.

I would like to output the answer to a percentage of my total database eg. 8/20 * 100 * = 40%

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE MILES BETWEEN 3 AND 5) / 
  (SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER) * 100 FROM CUSTOMER ;
```

But this gives me 20 rows of "40" which is the correct answer, I just don't want 20 rows of it.

Comment: Littlefoot explains your mistake in their answer. And here is a query with conditional aggregation, that does the same thing: `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN miles BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 1 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) FROM customer;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in a single query using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN miles BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN customer_id END)
       / COUNT(customer_id) * 100 AS percentage
FROM   customer;
```

If you use sub-queries then you will access the table twice and it will be less efficient.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you and everyone for your help. I am a total newbie so this was pretty daunting, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The final `FROM` should be from `DUAL` (it contains 1 row only), not `CUSTOMER` (which, apparently, contains 20 rows).

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE MILES BETWEEN 3 AND 5) /
       (SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER_ID) FROM CUSTOMER) * 100 as result
FROM DUAL;         --> here
```